# Which is the definition of a Horn formula being positive?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, programming

On [p208](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=208) of Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic

> Every  Horn  formula  is  a  formula  in conjunctive normal  form, ...,  every member of the conjunction has the form  (PHI), (PH2) or (PH3):
>
> (PH1)  $q$
>
> (PH2)  $(q_0  \land ... \land q_n  \to q)$
>
> (PH3)  $(\neg q_0  \lor ... \lor \neg q_n). $
>
> **Horn formulas of the form  (PH1) or (PH2) are called positive, those
> of the form  (PH3)  negative**.

Which is the definition of a  Horn formula  being positive:

- a formula in CNF, whose members are either PH1 or PH2? (My guess)
- a formula which is either PH1 or PH2? (By the last sentence in the quote) (My guess, after reading the remaining of p208 and p209)

Thanks.

Comment: I would have guessed that a positive Horn formula was a Horn formula which is also a positive formula, which would mean that each conjunct has the form PH1, since PH2 and PH3 are not positive formulas. I seem to recall seeing "strict Horn formula" used for a Horn formula where each conjunct is PH1 or PH2 but I could be remembering wrong, that would have been in a bygone millennium.

Comment: I deleted my answer after realizing I had not properly read Ebbinghaus' definition and your question. The notion of positivity makes sense for Horn *clauses*, i.e. members of the conjunction, which is what I was elaborating on in my answer; but I have nowhere seen it applied, nor do I see how it can be applied according to this definition, to entire Horn *formulas*.

Answer (score 1):

Compare with a different source: [Horn Formulas](https://www21.in.tum.de/teaching/logik/SS18/Slides/horn-prop.pdf).

> **Definition**: A formula $F$ in [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) is a *Horn formula* if every disjunction in $F$ contains at most one positive [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)).

> A disjunction in a Horn formula can equivalently be viewed as an
> implication $K \to B$ where $K$ is a conjunction of [atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_formula).

According to the above definition, (PH1), (PH2) and (PH3) are all examples of Horn formulas, because (PH2) : $(q_0 \land \ldots  \land q_n \to q)$, when written in CNF, will be:

> $(\lnot q_0 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot q_n \lor q)$

and we have only one (and thus: at most one) positive literal: $q$.

In conclusion, according to Ebbinghaus definition, an Horn formula is a formula:

> $(\lnot q_0 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot q_n \lor q) \land \ldots \land (\lnot r_0 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot r_m)$

where $n$ can be $0$.

---

Why in the following discussion regarding the *satisfiability* algorithm for Horn formulas the author consider only the *negative* and *positive* ones ?

Simply because, being an Horn formula $\alpha$ a conjunction, it will be satisfiable iff every conjunct is, and thus the author consider equivalently the set $\Delta$ of members of the conjunction $\alpha$.